# Angular 9 internationalization

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am trying to change our existing app with the new way of internationalization in `Angular 9`. Here is how I configured it in `angular.json`:

```
{
...
"projects": {
    "viewer": {
      ...
      "i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "bg": "src/locale/messages.bg.xlf"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              ...
            ],
            "styles": [
              ...
            ],
            "scripts": [
              ...
            ],
            "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "bg": {
              "localize": ["bg"]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "viewer:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "viewer:build:production"
            },
            "bg": {
              "browserTarget": "viewer:build:bg"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          ...
        },
        "test": {
          ...
        },
        "lint": {
          ...
        }
      }
    },
    "viewer-e2e": {
      ...
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

But when I run `ng serve --configuration=bg` it still serves the default `en` translation. Any ideas?

Comment: What's "viewer" in "viewer:build:bg"? Your project name is "my-project", is it just a typo?

Comment: @AkshayRana yes, sorry, it is a typo. The project name is `viewer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `aot` to `true` in your `angular.json` file. Without this, angular will use JIT mode, for which you need to dynamically provide the translations using the `TRANSLATIONS` token.

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "aot": true,
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently stuck with the same process. My understanding so far:

- Angular 9 'localize' asks for build configurations (such as 'production') plus localize configurations (such as 'bg')
- You only get the desired build by superimposing the two, ie `ng build --configuration=production,bg`
- By defining a list of 'locales' in 'i18n', you can use the very handy `--localize` directive to superimpose each configuration defined as 'locale'

So by running `ng build --configuration=production --localize` (or --prod), the build will take the 'production' configuration as a basis, and then superimpose each locale defined in i18n.locales on it.